# How to build cython pyx to pyd in anaconda(python3.6) in windows 8.1?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, struct, cython, cythonize

I have referred some websites to build pyx to pyd in Windows 8.1.I 'm using Anaconda Distribution with Spyder IDE, I have developed pyx file and unable to build in "Anaconda Command Prompt" 
Anaconda>

```
python setup.py build --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

and tried

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

getting following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 129 in __init__  
  if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

my simple pyx code is

```
cdef int fib(int n):    
    cdef int a, b, i
    a, b  = 1, 1
    for i in range(n):
       a, b = a+b, a
    return a
```

and my setup.py file as below..

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('fb.pyx'))
```

Howto get rid of this in windows 8.1? I would like use Struct and Socket libraries for my socket programming.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your .pyx or setup.py code AFAICT.
I am using Anaconda3 on windows 10 and it works.

The issue is with the compiler. Did you install mingw32 yourself?
It looks like whichever version you have cannot compile the code.
I got the same error for cygwin

But, the code compiled fine for me using the compiler included in Visual Studio 14 and the borlands compiler.

Try --compiler=bcpp (hopefully already be on your system)

or

Try installing: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
and run your compile command with --compiler=msvc (or just without specifying the compiler.)