# Cygwin compile error (windows 10, python 3.7, visual studio 2019)

Tags: python, cython

I want to build_ext a ".pyd" file but it didn't work.

I tried to update visual, update compilers etc .. nothing worked ...

I want to use this command:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=cygwin
```

with setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import os
os.environ["CC"] = "gcc-5.3.0"
os.environ["CXX"] = "gcc-5.3.0"

directives = {'linetrace': False, 'language_level': 3}
setup(ext_modules = cythonize('local_correlation.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'))
```

and i have it :

```
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize('local_correlation.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'))
  File "C:\Users\benfr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\benfr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\benfr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\benfr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
    force=self.force)
  File "C:\Users\benfr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)
  File "C:\Users\benfr\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 137, in __init__
    if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944304/how-to-build-cython-pyx-to-pyd-in-anacondapython3-6-in-windows-8-1

Comment: Thank you but I tried it, but it didn't work ... I have 4 compilers and no one is working. I checked installations etc ... I don't understand because it worked some months ago ... It is may be an update ...